# su: permission denied error

Tags: android

By using command prompt access the device shell/terminal. then use the su command getting permission denied error. Why this happening?

how can i solve this problem.

Comment: You need to root your device to be able to access super user priviledges. Ask google how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i have hear'd  of it, don't know exactly, but i think one needs to root the device in order to get those privileges......

Answer (score 0):

First try

```
shell>man su
```

The command su take some parameters like -l 
after that you have to enter the user password.
If you type:

```
su -l root
```

then the root password is going to be asked.
Probably you can cope your problem by using the "sudo" command.
(try "man sudo").

Comment: This is not applicable to the highly atypical-for-linux userspace and security model of android, please consider removing it.